# -webkit-animation-name: pop in JQuery

Tags: jquery, webkit, jquery-animate

I would like to reproduce the effect seen on http://madebyelephant.com/ (only works with a webkit browser) using JQuery.

The effect uses:

```
-webkit-animation-name: pop;
-webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
```

Does anybody know how to reproduce the same pop animation using JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/animate/ and http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Comment: Yes, I had a look at those. But it's that specific pop effect I am trying to recreate. Any pointers (as to what combination to use) would be helpful.

Comment: I don't think there is actually a specific pop effect, but you could do it by animating the width and height. If you look for some jquery plugins there might even be a 'scale' effect.

Comment: the scale effect is indeed a good suggestion but it does not work on all elements centering the scale... :(

Comment: in-case you are a techie - try to see how its done here - http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettypopin/ - I will also try and revert if it works!

Answer (score 1):

`pop` isn't a standard webkit animation, so they'd have to define it with keyframes in the stylesheet.

Looks like the elephants are scaling and fading in like so:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pop {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(.1);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    85% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Don't have time to do the jQuery for that right now, but write back if you need help with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).toggle("scale", { percent: 0 }, 1000);

or

$(this).hide("scale", {percent: 700, origin: 'center', fade: 'hide' }, 2000);

or 

$(this).hide("scale", {}, 1000);
```

Please be advised that it would not work clean for elements with background images. Apply it directly to images or css styled divs and would work out of the box!